# Android - Disable auto-forwarding on website

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to display a website in a WebView.
The problem is that it contains the following HTML-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; URL=subst_001.htm">
```

This causes the website do disappear (and the subst_001.htm, which contains an error message, appears)

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

*Clarification: I don't have (editing) access to the website I want to open.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Using a "custom" WebView does the trick.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

---

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(24)
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to add some condition to authorize the redirection in some case. Or add documentation to remember this, because this could be a problem in an futur web page that should be redirected.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I am absolutely sure that I do not want a redirect :)

Comment: Yet ;) So document this part to remember why this is here, in 6month, 1year, when you will have a page with a redirect (if you have), you will be happy to remember that this prevent it as it is.

Comment: I understand. Thanks! 